# Efficient way to have only the latest data and delete the rest from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I am trying to find the quickest way to delete the data from my Table. My logic is to only have the latest 2 days of data within Table1 for a given Lot_ID and ID is a unique Primary Key in the Table.

My data isn't much but it still takes me around 8-9 mins for the below query execution.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 select t.ID
from (select t1.*,
             DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Lot_ID order by TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(second, t1.starttime, '19700101') )           
              desc) as seqnum
      from  Table1 t1
     ) t
where seqnum >2
)
DELETE Table1 WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from CTE where CTE.ID = Table1.ID )
```

Is there a fastest or a better approach to do this?

Comment: temporal tables can do this for you (with a retention period for the history table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and delete directly from the cte rather than reopening the table:

```
with cte as(
    select dense_rank() over (
        partition by lot_id 
        order by try_convert(date, dateadd(second, t1.starttime, '19700101')) desc
    ) as seqnum
    from  table1 t1
)
delete from cte where seqnum > 2
```

Your query suggests that `startime` is an epoch timestamp (so an `int` datatype), so another possible optimization is to use arithmetics rather than date conversion:

```
with cte as(
    select dense_rank() over (
        partition by lot_id 
        order by t1.starttime / 60 / 60 / 24 desc
    ) as seqnum
    from  table1 t1
)
delete from cte where seqnum > 2
```

If none of that helps, then you might want to consider inversing the logic: that is, moving the records you want to retain to a temporary table, then tuncating and refilling the original table.

Comment: Thank you @GMB. Looks like Inversing the logic is the right way to go in my case as I need to look at the quickest way to execute this.  Rather than truncating, I dropped my main table and renamed the temp table with cte as
 (select t1.*,
             DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Lot_ID order by TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(second, t1.starttime, '19700101') )    
     desc) as seqnum
      from  Table1  t1
  ) 

select * into Test1 from cte where seqnum <=2 ;  --
drop table Table1;
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Test1', 'Table1';